# 24v ac coverted 12v dc for 30 watt LED

Tags: power-supply, current

I am facing annoying issues when converting 24V AC to 12 V DC. I want run 30 W LED and I have a limitation in input that I can only use 24V AC output of a transformer. I have the circuit as shown, but the problem is that the LED doesn't glow much, it is getting 12v but I am not sure about the current and R1 (as in figure) heats up very much.

Please help me reach my goal[image: Multisim simulation].

Comment: Do you think R1 will be limiting the available current?

Comment: LED datasheet required.

Comment: You've made your schematic very difficult to read for yourself and for everyone else. Put V+ on top and negative / GND on the bottom. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/how-change-circuit-to-get-15vdc1a-rather-than-15vdc-6a for a well laid-out version of your schematic.

Comment: _"Please help me reach my goal"_ Please state what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

The LM7812CT provides 12 volts at up to 1 amp. That's a typical maximum continuous output power of 12 watts.

> *I want run 30Watts LED*

There's your first problem. A 7812 is inappropriate for that power level.

Your second problem is the 1 kohm resistor will not pass anything like enough current to make a powerful LED operate without burning.  Try something like this: -

[image]

You'll still need the bridge rectifier and reservoir capacitors but those capacitors will need to be hundreds of uF, possibly 1000 uF or more to get a reasonably smooth DC output voltage with an AC input frequency at only 50 Hz.

Comment: what adjustment do you suggest i should make?

Comment: Use a buck current regulator circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a 2:1 autotransformer after your 24 ac? You'll have lower cos(phi), but for that much power, not really a matter. Then you use your straightener and a couple of capacitors in parallel.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question.